# Set a simple color gradient as the background of UIToolbar

Tags: ios, uitoolbar, uicolor, tintcolor, bartintcolor

I can easily change the UIToolbar background color thanks to the Bart Tint property in Interface Builder. However, I would like to use a simple, two-color vertical gradient as background.

The solution should work with any custom toolbar height, and my target is iOS 7+. If it must be done programmatically, both Objective-C and Swift are welcome.

**Edit**: based on the answers I'm doing this in `viewDidLoad`, but it makes no effect:

```
var gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = toolbar.bounds
gradient.colors = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.greenColor()]
toolbar.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
```

**Edit 2**: based on the answers, I replaced the following line, but it still makes no effect:

```
gradient.colors = [UIColor.redColor().CGColor, UIColor.greenColor().CGColor]
```

**Edit 3**: I got it. I had to set "Bar Tint" to "Default" in Interface Builder first, so that the tint is transparent and doesn't hide the programmatically added gradient layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CAGradientLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/index.html) for achieving this.

Objective C:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame            = yourToolbar.bounds;
gradient.colors           = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor], nil];
[yourToolbar.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Swift:

```
var gradient:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame               = yourToolbar.bounds
gradient.colors              = [UIColor.redColor().CGColor, UIColor.greenColor().CGColor]
yourToolbar.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
```

Comment: I'm using Swift and cannot find any "layer" under "CAGradientLayer", and I cannot find that "layer" property (I'm referring to the first line of your code)

Comment: Replaced it with `var gradient = CAGradientLayer()`. Compiles but still doesn't work.

Comment: No, but it compiles so that's not the issue. Anyway I tried to import it just in case and the result is the same.

Comment: Have you tried your code with a UIToolbar in iOS 7+ or this is just a general solution? Because for some reason it's not working for me.

Comment: Yes, I tried it in my iOS project running on iOS 7+ (It's in Objective C). Now checking in swift

Comment: @cprcrack: issue in your code, you need to convert it to CGColor, copy my answer and check

Comment: I got it. I had to set "Bar Tint" to "Default" in Interface Builder first, so that the tint is transparent and doesn't hide the programmatically added gradient layer.

Comment: @cprcrack: Happy to know that it worked for you. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

This works

```
    var gradient:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.toolbar.bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.redColor().CGColor, UIColor.greenColor().CGColor]
    self.toolbar.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
```

Comment: I tried it (including the `.CGColor`), and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried your code with a UIToolbar in iOS 7+ or this is just a general solution? Because for some reason it's not working for me.

Comment: I am trying it on iOS 8.1 simulator. No problem. Just a barebone project with UIToolbar.

Comment: I got it. I had to set "Bar Tint" to "Default" in Interface Builder first, so that the tint is transparent and doesn't hide the programmatically added gradient layer.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same way as setting a Gradient Background for UINavigationBar - you can use the `setBackgroundImage` method of UIToolbar.

Just add these two extensions:

```
extension UIImage {
    static func imageFromLayer (layer: CALayer) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(layer.frame.size)
        guard let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {return nil}
        layer.render(in: currentContext)
        let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return outputImage
    }
}

extension UIToolbar {
    func setGradientBackground(barFrame: CGRect, aColor: UIColor, bColor: UIColor, aX: CGFloat, bX: CGFloat, aY: CGFloat, bY: CGFloat) {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = frame
        gradientLayer.colors = [aColor.cgColor, bColor.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: aX, y: aY)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: bX, y: bY)
        if let image = UIImage.imageFromLayer(layer: gradientLayer) {
            self.setBackgroundImage(image, forToolbarPosition: .bottom, barMetrics: .default)
        }
    }
}
```

This creates a UIImage from a CAGradientLayer, and subsequently sets it as a background image of your UIToolbar. Then just apply it to your UIToolbar. For instance, a horizontal gradient from blue to white:

```
myToolbar.setGradientBackground(
                barFrame: navigationBar.frame,
                aColor: UIColor.blue,
                bColor: UIColor.white,
                aX: 0.0,
                bX: 1.0,
                aY: 0.5,
                bY: 0.5
            )
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

// Use this Code:

i=2;

```
        leftColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.03 green:0.20 blue:0.95 alpha:1.0];
rightColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.98 green:0.00 blue:0.89 alpha:1.0];
gradient.frame = self.font_imageview.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   (id)[rightColor CGColor],
                   (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor,
                   (id)[leftColor CGColor],nil];

[font_imageview.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);
gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom toolbar then maybe you face the size problem. **view_toolbar** can be any view, Here I found another perfect solution:

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
var bounds =  self.view_toolbar.bounds
bounds.size.height += UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
gradientLayer.frame = bounds
gradientLayer.colors = [colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark]
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)

self.view_toolbar.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```